# What's the difference of between [b,a] =[a,b] and const [b,a]=[a,b]

Tags: javascript, destructuring

In destructing, the result does differ between these two codes. I'm not sure why.

The hint says `const [b,a] = [a,b]` will result in the value of `a,b` as `undefined` (simple assignment rule left to right). I can't understand why it happens.

```js
let a = 8, b = 6;
(() => {
    [b,a]=[a,b];

})();
console.log(a); // should be 6
console.log(b); // should be 8
```

The result changed but, when const is attached, the value isn't switched.

Comment: _"The hint"_? What hint?

Comment: @j08691 homework hint probably

Comment: `const` means its constant....? as in it cant be changed...

Comment: It is  freeCodeCamp process. I'm in stuck so I click "The hint" they give me the hint like that. But I can't understand what they say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The hint says `const [b,a] = [a,b]` will result in the value of a,b as undefined(simple assignment rule left to right). I can't understand why it happens.

It wouldn't. If FreeCodeCamp says it does, it's wrong.

If you added `const` before `[b,a] = [a,b]`, you'd get a ReferenceError because you'd be *shadowing* the outer `a` and `b` with inner ones, and trying to use the inner ones before they were initialized:

```js
let a = 8, b = 6;
(() => {
    const [b,a]=[a,b];

})();
console.log(a); // should be 6
console.log(b); // should be 8
```

If they meant using `const` instead of `let` in the initial declaration, that *also* wouldn't have the effect they list. Instead, you'd get a TypeError because you'd be trying to assign to a constant:

```js
const a = 8, b = 6;
(() => {
    [b,a]=[a,b];

})();
console.log(a); // should be 6
console.log(b); // should be 8
```

Comment: Thanks! shadowing means the outer variable and the inner variable names are same?

Comment: @박충호 - It means there are two `a` variables and two `b` variables: The ones inside the function and the ones outside the function. You can't use the ones outside the function from within the function if it declares them within the function, because that declaration *shadows* (hides) the outer variable. ("variable" in this context means "variable or constant". The technical term is *binding*.)